# Java .policy file - how to prevent java.util.Date() from being accessible

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I am playing around with the java .policy file and was wondering how I could go about doing something like preventing calls to java.util.Date(), as an example.

I just want to get a better sense of the .policy file works and how it can be used to sandbox code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be out of luck there I'm afraid.

As Paŭlo Ebermann says, `package.access` can block out package hierarchies. You can be more precise about this with a custom `SecurityManager`, which is usually a damn good indication you are doing something really dodgy.

In general you can make a `ClassLoader` that doesn't always delegate to its parent. Technically against the current Java SE spec, although the Java EE spec encourages it. You could block out `java.util.Date`. It's still accessible through reflection if any other class references it, or you can get an instance of it. You could block out the transitive closure of uses of `Date`, including those that in some way return a `Date`. However, to complete the scheme with your minimal date you'd have to load a `java.util.Date` in your class loader, which you can't along with all other `java.*` classes.

So, err, replace the `java.util.Date` class in rt.jar (possibly using a Java Agent), and substitute in any class you don't want to restrict `new Date()` with `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`.

(Btw, +1 to anything that reduces the dependency on `System.currentTimeMillis()` and other magic methods.)

Answer (score 2):

To restrict access to certain packages, you have actually to change not the `.policy` file, but the `security.properties`. There is an entry `package.access=...` which lists the packages for which RuntimePermissions are needed. So, you can't restrict specifically the access to a single class, only to a whole package (including subpackages, if needed), i.e. `java.util`.
(You can alternatively access this by the `Security.?etProperty` methods.)

If you did this, you later can add the right RuntimePermission to the Policy to let the "good" code use it.

I think quite a good part of the JRE would cease working if you restrict access to java.util, so better try another class for testing.

Comment: At what path security.properties is present

Answer (score 1):

The way the sandbox mostly works is that there are calls from classes that do security-sensitive stuff to the current SecurityManager to check whether or not such a call should succeed. Since the Date class isn't perceived to be security-sensitive, no such calls exist in it's code and that's why - as explained by Tom and Paulo - it is very difficult to restrict it.

For example, in contrast: File operations are perceived to be security sensitive and that's why the File class has calls to the SecurityManager. As an example the delete method:

```
public boolean delete() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkDelete(path);
    }
    return fs.delete(this);
}
```

And thanks to the SecurityManager check in the File class you can restrict File delete operations in the .policy file with more ease.