# Block some programs accessing only util package

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to block some programs to access `util` package.
I'm working on `Ubuntu` and even after providing 770 permission to `util` folder as a root, my program as a normal user is able to compile and run per-se

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
```

It runs successfully. I tried searching and went across the following link
[Java .policy file - how to prevent java.util.Date() from being accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5083619/1397699)

as explained there it can be done by security.access can any one show me right direction to block the usage of `util` package.

Comment: ...Why would you possibly want to do this?

Comment: just want my brother not to use util package rather try n learn coding

Comment: ..._Every_ Java programmer should learn to use the util package as quickly as they can.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `chmod` on a directory is not what you need. You can try using a `SecurityManager`.